# Setting multiple values for option using javascript (add)

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<select id='selectid' onchange="selectchange()">

</select>

<script>
for (let i=0;i<10;i++)
{
 var select = document.getElementById("selectid");
    var option = document.createElement("option");
     option.text = "text="+i;
    option.value = i;
    select.add(option);
}
function selectchange()
{
alert(document.getElementById("selectid").value);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

### Description

1. Here i have been using javascript to add options for my select tag

### I Needed

1. I need to store more than one data using my existing javascript code like for value=1 option need to add another value for the option tag like value2=a, and for value=2 as value2=b

### Example syntax

```
 var select = document.getElementById("selectid");
            var option = document.createElement("option");
             option.text = "text="+i;
            option.value = i;
            option.value2 = a;
            select.add(option);
```

I need to add two values for my option using the above syntax.

Comment: Are you planning to add custom attributes to the option? your best bet is this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

Comment: I tried to add like (option.data-value2) but it's throwing an error

Comment: Do you want your other values to be accessed from the `document.getElementById("selectid")` ?

Comment: yes, i need to access all of my values but using separate attributes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `setAttribute` and `getAttribute`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<select id='selectid' onchange="selectchange()">

</select>

<script>
for (let i=0;i<10;i++) {
 var select = document.getElementById("selectid");
    var option = document.createElement("option");
     option.text = "text="+i;
    option.value = i;
    option.setAttribute("data", Math.random());
    option.setAttribute("data1", `data1_${Math.random()}`);
    select.add(option);
}

function selectchange() {
  const select = document.getElementById("selectid");
  const data = select.options[select.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data");
  const data1 = select.options[select.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data1");
  console.log(`value is: ${select.value} and data is: ${ data } data1 is: ${data1}`);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this is what you were looking for!!

Answer (score 1):

**The first solution** is to use [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <select id='selectid' onchange="selectchange()">

  </select>

  <script>
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      var select = document.getElementById("selectid");
      var option = document.createElement("option");
      option.text = "text=" + i;
      option.value = i;
      option.dataset['var-1'] = i;
      option.dataset['var-2'] = 'value2';
      option.dataset['var-3'] = 'value3'; // and etc.
      select.add(option);
    }

    function selectchange() {
      const selectedOption = document.getElementById("selectid").selectedOptions[0]
      console.log(selectedOption.dataset);
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**The second solution** is to use an external variable to store additional data:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <select id='selectid' onchange="selectchange()">

  </select>

  <script>
    const dataStore = {};

    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      var select = document.getElementById("selectid");
      var option = document.createElement("option");
      option.text = "text=" + i;
      option.value = i;
      select.add(option);
      dataStore[i] = {
        var1: i,
        var2: 'var2',
        var3: 'var3'
      };
    }

    function selectchange() {
      const index = document.getElementById("selectid").value
      const value = dataStore[index]
      console.log(value);
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```